# Как сделать грамотно эффект пагинации в фильтре?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

В общем, есть фильтр статей по годам, выглядит он следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очевидно, что список годов слишком длинный. Хотелось бы нечто похожее на:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Любые советы/идеи/ссылки/гем are welcome

- что происходит при нажатии на многоточие?
- каким образом юзер получит доступ ко всем годам?

Места мало, поэтому вариант 2017 ... 2014 ... 2011 не самый лучший.

Comment: Сделать их выпадающим списком?

Comment: Чтобы сократить используемую площадь экрана, можно писать 17 16 15 14 и так далее. 2017 - 2011 + 1 это всего 6 чисел. Потом, кто вообще захочет выбирать публикации в вашем блоге по годам? Это не имеет смысла, это не информативно. Уберите эти года.

Comment: Потом, кто станет кликать на "награды", "публикации", "команда"? Никто. Такая подача информации не имеет смысла.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov я не дизайнер, а верстальщик, правила задает заказчик

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать горизонтальный скрол списка годов. Начало прокручиваемой области начинается после элемента `Все` и заканчивается перед `...`. Таким образом пользователь будет как бы "вытягивать" список из `...`. Когда все года будут "вытянуты", `...` пропадёт.

Comment: Может, у вас есть на примете демо такого решения?

Comment: Нет, нету. Могу попробовать реализовать на js, но это только на следующей неделе

Comment: если вам не трудно, то, конечно, был бы рад)